# Check whether the extension is allowed or not using js strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have a system where the user specifies the extension and the system would return true if the given extension is allowed and false if its not allowed. The system has a preset list of file extensions that determine whether the given extension is allowed and disallowed.

**If allowed list is empty then it means all are allowed except the ones in disallowed list.
If disallowed list is empty then it means all are allowed and there is no disallowing of extensions.
When both are empty then all are allowed.**

I have tried with

```js
var allowed = "";
var disallowed = "xlsx, docx, png";

function testAllowedOrNot(str) {
  var disallowedArray = disallowed.split(",").map(function(ext) {
    return ext.trim().toLowerCase()
  });

  var allowedArray = allowed.split(",").map(function(ext) {
    return ext.trim().toLowerCase()
  });

  return allowedArray.includes(str) && !disallowedArray.includes(str)

}

console.log(testAllowedOrNot("csv")) //must be true
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("xlsx")) //must be false
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("ico")) //must be true
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("jpg")) //must be true
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("docx")) //must be false
```

But its returning all as false. How can I change my code so I get the intended output.

Comment: Yeah because your allowed list is empty

Comment: `allowed` is empty so `allowedArray.includes(str)` will _always_ be `false`

Comment: `return (allowedArray.includes(str) || allowedArray.lenght === 0) && !disallowedArray.includes(str)`

Comment: I have revised my question for better clarity. What I am expecting.

Comment: But its returning all as false. How can I change my code so I get the intended output.

Comment: `allowedArray.includes(str)` will always return false since you have empty string on the `allowed` variable

Comment: Why not post this as answer?

Comment: This is always returning false for all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the comments why your code did not work.

You are missing the test for empty allowedArray

I had to rewrite the code in case you have an allowed

It does not make much sense to have BOTH allowed and disallowed so perhaps rethink this?

```js
const allowed = "";
const disallowed = "xlsx,docx,png"
const disallowedArray = disallowed.split(",").map(ext => ext.trim().toLowerCase()).filter(ext => ext !== "");
const allowedArray = allowed.split(",").map(ext => ext.trim().toLowerCase()).filter(ext => ext !== "")
const testAllowedOrNot = str => {
  if (allowedArray.length > 0) return allowedArray.includes(str)
  return disallowedArray.length === 0 || !disallowedArray.includes(str)
};

console.log(testAllowedOrNot("csv")) //must be true
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("xlsx")) //must be false
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("ico")) //must be true
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("jpg")) //must be true
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("docx")) //must be false
```

Comment: @CodeGuy Please see my updated answer. There are pitfalls

Comment: Here is the use case https://www.labnol.org/download-gmail-file-extensions-4475 where those guys are using both allowed and disallowed list. I am unsure why?

Comment: Also your map returns an array with one empty string, so I had to recode again

Comment: Yes this is perfect, when there is an empty allowed it would allow all except disallowed list. When there are extensions in allowed list, we need to only allow the allowed list and disallow the disallowed list.

Comment: But only allow allow list makes disallow completely redundant

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- The allowedArray will always contain one element, since splitting the empty string by a character will return the empty string
- You only want to check if the given extension is on the blacklist, if you don't use the whitelist (meaning if there are no elements in allowedArray)

```js
var allowed = "";
var disallowed = "xlsx, docx, png";

function testAllowedOrNot(str) {
  var disallowedArray = disallowed.split(",").map(function(ext) {
    return ext.trim().toLowerCase()
  });

  var allowedArray = [];
  if (allowed.length > 0) {
    allowedArray = allowed.split(",").map(function(ext) {
      return ext.trim().toLowerCase()
    });
  }

  if (allowedArray.length > 0) {
    return allowedArray.includes(str);
  } else {
    return !disallowedArray.includes(str);
  }
}

console.log(testAllowedOrNot("csv")) //must be true
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("xlsx")) //must be false
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("ico")) //must be true
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("jpg")) //must be true
console.log(testAllowedOrNot("docx")) //must be false
```